# ggplot bar with percentage from categorical data

Tags: r, ggplot2

my data is

```
Category  Produkt.Segment
A         bundle
A         digital
B         digital
B         digital
B         bundle
C         digital
D         bundle
D         bundle
D         digital
D         bundle
```

How can I make a ggplot-bar facet wrap by Product.Segment from variable 'Category' in percentages (preferably with labels on the top of the bars)?
Any idea? 
I have tried something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Category))+
 geom_bar(fill="grey40")+scale_x_discrete()+
 theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue"))+
 ggtitle("Categories by Produkt Segments")+
 ylab("Frequency")+
 xlab("Category")+
 facet_grid(~Produkt.Segment)+
 scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format())
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Is there anything you've already tried?

Comment: Hi, I have tried to compute the percentages manually in new column however sum() function does not work on categorical data: count(df$category)/sum(count/df$category) will not work. Moreover, scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format()) just makes out of the y count a percent value( adding 2 zeros and % sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
 all <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
                      Category  Produkt.Segment
    A         bundle
                      A         digital
                      B         digital
                      B         digital
                      B         bundle
                      C         digital
                      D         bundle
                      D         bundle
                      D         digital
                      D         bundle")


ggplot(aes(x = Category, y = Produkt.Segment), data = all) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..) * 100, fill = Produkt.Segment))
```

[image]

and with the `wrap` for segment

```
ggplot(aes(x = Category, y = Produkt.Segment), data = all) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..) * 100, fill = Produkt.Segment)) +
  facet_wrap(~Produkt.Segment)
```

If you want to have percent per group, I'd do it like this but I am sure that there are guys here that could do it in more simple way

```
library(dplyr)
all1 <- group_by(all, Produkt.Segment, Category) %>% arrange(Produkt.Segment) %>% summarise(il = n()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Produkt.Segment) %>% mutate(per = il/sum(il))

ggplot(aes(x = Category, y = per), data = all1) + geom_histogram(stat = "identity")  + 
  facet_wrap(~Produkt.Segment)  + ylab("Percent")
```

Comment: Thanks
The facet wrap worked however it takes into account the percentages from all the df. Can you point out how to make to "wrap" in a way that it would calculate the percentual points from its own group (Product.Segment)? and how to add the bar labels to individual bins?

Comment: @Pat I added the solution for your question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your contribution @Mateusz1981, yes with data manipulation using dplyr package I can get to the desired outcome, however, the closest I got to a 'clean cut' solution was this:

```
ggplot(aes(x = Category, y = Produkt.Segment, fill=Produkt.Segment), data = all)+geom_bar(aes(y = ..density.., group=Produkt.Segment), binwidth = 25)+facet_grid(.~Produkt.Segment)+theme(legend.position="none")+ggtitle("Product Segments")+ylab("[n]")+xlab("Category")+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

Still, I do not know how to add labels on the individual bins

[The Output from R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SMtz.png)